# postgress error: invalid input syntax for integer: ""

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql

i used reactjs, nodejs, express and postgress with knex

here's the code

```
app.post('/new-story', (req, res) => {
    const {title, description, mature, id} = req.body;
    db.select('stories').from('users').where('id' = id)
    .then(data => {
       const stories = data[0].stories;
       db('story')
          .returning('*')
          .insert({
              title: title,
              category: category,
              description: description,
              mature: mature,
              entry: stories
       })
       .then(story => {
             res.json(story)
       })
})
.catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

and i receive and error

> error: invalid input syntax for integer: "" at Connection.parseE, at
>   Connection.parseMessage, at Socket,

here's the code in my react app

```
onSaveDate = () => {
   fetch('http://localhost:3001/new-story', {
       method: 'post',
       header: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
       body: JSON.stringify({
            id: this.state.id,
            title: this.state.title,
            description: this.state.description,
            category: this.state.category,
            mature: this.state.mature
})
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(story => console.log(story))
}
```

i tried to test my end point in postman and it worked, idk when i tried in my react app it said error: invalid input syntax for integer: ""

and here's the database

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   id serial primary key,
   name VARCHAR(100),
   email text unique not null,
   stories bigint default 0,
   joined timstamp not null
);
```

and here's my table story

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   id_book serial primary key,
   entry bigint default 0,
   title varchar(100),
   category varchar(100),
   description varchar(100),
   mature varchar(10)
);
```

what i would like to is stories and entry to be the same, i cannot figure out the error in postgress node

Answer (score 1):

I got an error because my id column is empty, so if anyone come across error like

> error: invalid input syntax for integer: "" at Connection.parseE, at
>   Connection.parseMessage, at Socket,

you should check the database if it was empty or not